# fit a smooth spline through a 3D point cloud in python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I have a problem where I have a bunch of points in 3D space. So, in python something like:

```
[[247.559787, 236.83298, 15],
[258.864134, 212.782486, 17],
[209.799014, 212.649149, 19],
[174.486667, 204.480421, 20],
[159.516284, 194.906524, 22],
[164.609462, 187.647712, 29],
[166.687175, 191.171619, 29],
[152.217906, 218.902805, 31]]
```

These points represent the midpoint through a tube like structure. I was wondering how to smoothly interpolate between these points using some python libraries.

Ultimately, what I would like is to query this interpolated function about where it cuts a certain plane. For example, once I have an interpolationg function, can I ask where it cuts, for example, the plane at `z = 25` for example?